# Documentation for Helm Charts (Prometheus)

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I just got started using Helm Charts (Prometheus Community), but I'm having a hard time figuring out, how things work. I'm using the following Helm Chart: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts and I was already able to adjust certain parameters via values.yaml file for example:

```
grafana:
  plugins: 
    - grafana-worldmap-panel
    - marcusolsson-gantt-panel
```

However, I'm also facing some issues:

1. Adding custom scrape configs
2. Making Prometheus and Grafana persistent around pod restarts

What's the best way to approach such issues? The internet was not helpful so far.